# Hidden variable not passing when select box is disabled in php

Tags: php, html

I have two pages lets say `first.php`, `second.php`.

`first.php`:

```
<form name=register method="post" action="second.php">
Name:<input type="text" name="username" value=<?=$username?> >
Email:<input type="email" name="email" value=<?=$email?> >
Hobbies:<select name="hobbies" id="hobbies" disabled>
<option value="cricket">cricket</option>
<option value="football">football</option>
</select>
</form>
```

`second.php`:

```
<?
print_r($_POST);
```

I am getting only name and email and not select value.

If I print the post value I am not getting the select value, but when I am removing the disabled in select, I am getting the select value in hidden.

In this scenario, I don't want the user to select the select box and when I submit the form, I should get the value in hidden in `second.php`.

I have tried many possible ways, to no avail.
Can anybody suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: If select box is disable and no default selection provide then what you expect the output will be. You need to default select one option.

Comment: Tricks: If the checkbox is disabled, use javascript / jquery to generate a hidden one at the bottom of the form.

Comment: Using `disabled` in html not post the values of elements.You need to pass hidden value

Comment: just use readonly instead of disabled

Comment: i have removed and kept as readonly but i am able to select the value in select box...

Answer (score 0):

Disabled tags can't be send to POST. Change `disabled` to `readonly` or `hidden`

Comment: its not working can you suggest a peace of code for this senario @kristiyan

Answer (score 0):

You cant post a disabled field. Maybe you can disable the selectbox right before you post it or you could (like the comments tell you) get a hidden value to be posted that has the standard value you want. If the select box is able to be posted(so not disabled) you can overwrite the hidden value with the select value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Jquery before the form is submitted.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#register').submit(function() {
    $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In

> second.php

you have to create a validation to check that user can be registered or no.

```
    if($this->user->can_register()){
        $this->user->save($_POST['hobbies']);
    }
```

Because if only with `html` or `js` exception is not enough to handle that case. Some users can just inspect element and remove the disabled element.